# How to increment every number in a bash variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script to control Linux perf. As you may know, perf takes core list which can be specified in 1 of the three ways.

1. -C1 #core 1 only
2. -C1-4 # core 1 through 4
3. -C1,3 # core 1 and 3

Currently, I have an environment variable CORENO which will control -C$CORENO.

However, I need to offset CORENO by a fix offset (I.e.2)

I could do ((CORENO+=2)) but that only work for case 1.

Is there a Linux/bash trick to allow me to apply fix offset to every number in a bash variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on Linux, here's some GNU sed:

```
addtwo() {
  sed -re 's/[^0-9,-]//g; s/[0-9]+/$((\0+2))/g; s/^/echo /e;' <<< "$1"
}

addtwo "1"
addtwo "1-4"
addtwo "3,4,5"
```

It will output:

```
3
3-6
5,6,7
```

It works by replacing all numbers with `$((number+2))` and evaluating the result as a shell command. A whitelisting of allowed characters is applied first to avoid any security issues.

Comment: This gives me another practical example of using sed!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `seq`

```
for core in `seq 2 10`; do
  echo CORENO=$core
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve upvoted the sed-based answer from @that other guy because I like it more than mine, which is a “pure bash” solution, consisting of a recursive function.

```
function increment () {
    local current="$1" n=$(($2))
    if [[ "$current" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo $((current+n))
    elif [[ $current == *,* ]]; then
        echo $(increment ${current%%,*} $n),$(increment ${current#*,} $n)
    elif [[ $current == *-*-* ]]; then
        echo ERROR
    elif [[ $current == *-* ]]; then
        echo $(increment ${current%-*} $n)-$(increment ${current#*-} $n)
    else
        echo ERROR
    fi
}

CORENO=3-5
CORENO=$(increment $CORENO 2)
echo $CORENO

increment 3-5,6-8 3
```

My function will print `ERROR` when given an illegal argument. The one from @that other guy is much more liberal...